# jsTree: Try to split id of a node - Split is not a function

Tags: jquery, split, jstree

i have a jstree and try to get the selected id. The ids are like this one:

```
<ul id="jstree1">
<li id="group_number">...</li>
<li id="a_1">...</li>
<li id="a_2">...</li>
<li id="b_1">...</li>
<li id="b_2">...</li>
</ul>
```

I like to split this id by "_".

So i try

```
($('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_selected()).split('_');
```

But i get the Error Split is not a function.

I also tried:

```
$('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_selected().split('_');
```

and get the same error.

How can i split the id in two strings?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: I don't know jstree, but from the doc, get_selected return an array.

Comment: If you want to split the id, you must first acquire the id. I'm guessing that `$('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_selected()` returns either a DOM node or a jQuery collection.

Answer (score 0):

`get_selected()` returns an array of node IDs:
http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=get_selec&f=get_selected%28[full]%29

If you assume you will always have a single node selected you can do this:
`$('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_selected()[0].split('_');`